# Partially highlight title in tcolorbox environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, highlighting, tikz-positioning

I would like to improve my solution to the following goal. A `tcolorbox` environment with a title that is partially highlighted.
[image: The goal]

Thanks to the great answers here and the awesome `tcolorbox` docs. I achieved this solution, it's so hacky though, the highlighting part is what I don't like:

1. It has repeated code (as the section title),
2. The lengths are experimental, I would like it to go from the edge of the page to 2 or 3 letters in.
3. Use of `\vphantom` doesn't seem necessary if the highlighting is somehow linked to the title.

```tex
\usepackage[a4paper, bottom=1cm, top=1cm, right = 0.5cm, left = 0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\sectionTitle}[1]{
% begin bad highlighting code
  \node[inner sep=5pt,text width=0.21\textwidth,
      align=none, rectangle, fill=yellow,
      below right, font=\LARGE]
      at ([xshift=-0.5\textwidth]frame.north west)
  {%
    \vphantom{THI}
  };
% end bad highlighting code
  \node[inner sep=5pt,outer sep=0pt,text width=0.25\textwidth,
      align=none,
      below right, font=\LARGE]
      at ([xshift=-0.3\textwidth]frame.north west) (SECTIONTITLE)
  {%
    #1
  };
}
\newtcolorbox{mycustombox}[1]{
  blanker,
  width=0.6\textwidth,enlarge left by=0.3\textwidth,
  before skip=6pt,
  breakable,
  overlay unbroken and first={%
    \sectionTitle{#1}
},
  overlay unbroken and last={%
    \sectionTitle{#1}
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{mycustombox}{My Section Title}
  Content of this section
\end{mycustombox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok. You don't like the highlighting section but why? what do you like it?

Comment: I made edits that explain why i don't like the highlighting part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is too much hacky or redundant code in your original approach. Also, I don't quite understand what you want to achieve, so I am unsure whether this better suits your needs.

I changed the following:

- The `xshift` of the yellow background now  shifts it exactly to the left page border.
- The contents of the yellow node are irrelevant if you want to have a fixed width, so I changed it to `\strut`. In case the width should depend on the text of the title, see below for an alternative solution.
- I used the `anchor` option to place the nodes and removed all unnecessary options.
- I merged the options `overlay unbroken and first` and `overlay unbroken and last` to just `overlay` because this essentially does the same.

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, bottom=1cm, top=1cm, right=0.5cm, left=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[skins, breakable]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\sectionTitle}[1]{
  \node[inner sep=5pt, anchor=north west, font=\LARGE, 
    text depth=0pt, fill=yellow, text width=1.5cm]
    at ([xshift={-0.3\textwidth-\evensidemargin-1in}]frame.north west) {\strut};
  \node[inner sep=5pt, anchor=north west, font=\LARGE]
    at ([xshift={-0.3\textwidth}]frame.north west) {#1};
}
\newtcolorbox{mycustombox}[1]{
  blanker,
  width=0.6\textwidth,
  enlarge left by=0.3\textwidth,
  before skip=6pt,
  breakable,
  overlay={
    \sectionTitle{#1}
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mycustombox}{My Section Title}
  Content of this section
\end{mycustombox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want to have the yellow highlighting to end exactly after the third character of the section title, you could do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, bottom=1cm, top=1cm, right=0.5cm, left=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[skins, breakable]{tcolorbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \getfirstletters } { m m } {
    \str_use:N \str_range:Nnn { #1 } { 1 } { #2 } 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\sectionTitle}[1]{
  \node[inner sep=5pt, anchor=north west, font=\LARGE, 
    text depth=0.5ex, fill=yellow, 
    execute at begin node=\hspace*{\dimexpr\evensidemargin+1in-5pt\relax}]
    at ([xshift={-0.3\textwidth-\evensidemargin-1in}]frame.north west) {\phantom{\getfirstletters{#1}{3}}};
  \node[inner sep=5pt, anchor=north west, font=\LARGE]
    at ([xshift={-0.3\textwidth}]frame.north west) {#1};
}
\newtcolorbox{mycustombox}[1]{
  blanker,
  width=0.6\textwidth,
  enlarge left by=0.3\textwidth,
  before skip=6pt,
  breakable,
  overlay={
    \sectionTitle{#1}
  },
}

\begin{document}

\begin{mycustombox}{My Section Title}
  Content of this section
\end{mycustombox}

\bigskip

\begin{mycustombox}{WWWW}
  Content of this section
\end{mycustombox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I created a little helper macro that allows you to get the first three (or any other number of) letters of a string. To get the first three letters of "Hello", use `\getfirstletters{Hello}{3}`.

Comment: Awesome, I thought I might be able to combine the highlighting and the title somehow. But this is great since I got to know `at ([xshift={-0.3\textwidth-\evensidemargin-1in}]frame.north west) {\strut};`

Comment: @abdulhaq-e you somehow need to draw the yellow highlighting separately, either using a `\node` or a `\fill` command. At least, this is much simpler than trying to have the node that contains the title a colored background.